# Проблема с Яндекс.Карты API 2.1

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, карты, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Пытаюсь сделать через Яндекс API, чтобы по введенному адресу определяло координаты пользователя, а после проверяло, входят ли эти координаты в многоугольник (который я сделал в яндекс картах и выгрузил все координаты всех точек). Получить координаты у меня получилось, но почему-то всегда выводит false, хотя ввожу координаты внутри многоугольника. Мне кажется либо проблема с заданием координат, либо формата ввода этих координат в функцию, хотя уже пробовал по-разному.

```
    function addAddress(){
    //заносим текст формы в переменную
    var t= $("#new_address").val();
    var allow = false;

    //определяем координаты по адресу
    ymaps.geocode(t).then
    (
        function(res)
        {  
            if(res.geoObjects.get(0)){
                var MyGeoObj = res.geoObjects.get(0)
                //извлечение координат
                //var first = MyGeoObj.geometry.getCoordinates()[0];
                //var second = MyGeoObj.geometry.getCoordinates()[1];
                var myPolygon = new ymaps.geometry.Polygon([   [[37.40815810400387,55.87601838654848],[37.48506240087887,55.60252993980813],[37.85035781103513,55.76468609651485],[37.40815810400387,55.87601838654848]]   ]);
                //информация о карте
                myPolygon.options.setParent(myMap.options);
                myPolygon.setMap(myMap);
                //проверка вхождения
               console.log(myPolygon.contains( [MyGeoObj.geometry.getCoordinates()[0], MyGeoObj.geometry.getCoordinates()[1] ] ) ? allow = true : allow = false)
                //сохраняем если входит в полигон
                if(allow){
                    // всё хорошо, делаем что надо
                }

            }else{
                console.log('Адрес не найден!')
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: [Здесь](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/delivery_zones) можно посмотреть пример реализации проверки адреса на попадание в зону полигона